# Invoke-WebRequest without OutFile?

Tags: powershell, default, file-location, invoke-webrequest

I used Invoke-WebRequest in Powershell to download a file without using the `-OutFile` parameter, and, from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6), the file should've ended up in the directory I was in. However, there is nothing. Response was OK, no error was shown.

What could've happened to that file? Am I mistaken about how Invoke-WebRequest should work without an Out parameter?

Thanks!

Note: I know I can easily download the file using the parameter, but it's pretty big and I'd like to make sure it doesn't end up clogging disk space somewhere I don't need

Comment: If you dont specify a **PATH**, the response will be saved in the current location. If you omit the `-OutFile` parameter completely, it won't be saved on a file at all

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [linked docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6):

> By default, `Invoke-WebRequest` returns the results to the pipeline.

That is, in the absence of `-OutFile` *no* file is created.
(If you don't capture or redirect the output, it will print to the host (console).)

As [techguy1029](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10350118/techguy1029) notes in a comment on the question, the current directory only comes into play if you *do* use 
`-OutFile` but specify a mere file *name* rather than a *path*.

Additionally:

- In **v7.4+** of [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you may now specify *just* a *directory path*, in which case the the last segment of the (possibly redirected, ultimate) target URL is implicitly used as the file name.
  As of this writing (v7.4.1), there are two problems with this feature.

  - Using the `-Verbose` switch currently doesn't reveal the file name used (whose name won't be obvious, if URL redirections were involved), only the download *directory*: [GitHub issue #21081](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21081)
  - Similarly it would be helpful to be able to determine the downloaded file's full path *programmatically*, via the response object (in combination with `-PassThru`), which is the subject of the feature request in [GitHub issue #21082](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21082)
- A planned *future enhancement* (which will probably land in v7.5 at the earliest) is to use the *server-suggested* file name rather than the last URL segment, namely via a `Content-Disposition` field in the response header.
  However, work on the relevant PR, [GitHub PR #19385](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/19385), seems to have stalled as of this writing.

---

As an aside:

- To-pipeline output is a *response object* of [`WebResponseObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.webresponseobject)-derived class, whereas only the value of the response's *body* (the equivalent of property value `.Content`) is saved with `-OutFile`.
- Using the `-PassThru` switch in combination with `-OutFile` causes the response object to be emitted as well (by default, a download produces no direct output).

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11671#issue-554620226

Comment: Thanks, @RokeJulianLockhart - please see my update for the current state of this feature request.

Answer (score 5):

Lets talk about what the Microsoft documentation says for [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)

> *"
>   -OutFile : Specifies the output file for which this cmdlet saves the response body. Enter a path and file name. If you omit the path, the
>   default is the current location. "*

The Key word here is if a **Path** is omitted it will use the current path.

the **-OutFile** is a parameter of type **String**

The usage to save to **current path** would be

```
Invoke-webrequest "http://Test.com/test.pdf" -OutFile "Test.pdf"
```

else to have a **custom path**

```
Invoke-webrequest "http://Test.com/test.pdf" -OutFile "C:\Test\Test.Pdf"
```