# How to download file with powershell?

Tags: powershell

In the past I did use :

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$url = "https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6-x64.msi"
$folder = "C:\Users\test\Downloads"

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $folder)
```

When I try today it shows this error

```
  Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
  At line:1 char:5
  +     $WebClient.DownloadFile($url, $folder)
  +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

I tried to fix with suggestions found but none worked.

Comment: What a great 6 line error message saying basically nothing!

Comment: Need to include the Leaf file name in the destination folder path. I.e the absolute path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to extract the file name so you have a full path for the outfile, but this will work:

```
$url = "https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6-x64.msi"
$fullPath = "C:\Users\test\Downloads\node-v14.17.6-x64.msi"
Invoke-WebRequest $url -outfile $fullPath
```

Comment: Note that when downloading large files which prompt a progress bar, it is recommended to set `$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` before `Invoke-WebRequest` (you can set it back to the old value, usually `Continue`, after). This is because the progress counter trips for *every. single. byte*. This actually adds a huge amount of overhead especially for larger files. A several gig file can take the better part of an hour to download if the progress bar shows, but will finish in a fraction of the time without it.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [James World's effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69124660/45375):

To clarify:

> In the past I did use:

**[`System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile) *always* required a *file* path as the second argument - passing just a *directory* path - as desirable as that is - did *not* work**.

Obviously, **it would be convenient to be able to specify just a local *directory* path, so as to have the *file name* part be *implied***, either by:

- the `filename` attribute of the `Content-Disposition` response-header field
- or, in its absence, by the *last URL component* - assuming it is a legal file name.

Regrettably, **the `-OutFile` parameters of PowerShell's [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) and [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlets also do *not* support passing a *directory* path**, as of PowerShell 7.2.

- [*Update*: **v7.4+ now *does* allow passing just a directory path**; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57912181/45375) for details and a potential additional future enhancement for supporting *server-suggested* download file names] [GitHub issue #11671](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11671)
  is the latest of several feature requests that asks for addressing this limitation. While such an enhancement has been green-lit in principle, initially as an experimental feature, no one has stepped up to implement it so far.

---

In the case at hand, you can programmatically derive the target file name from the *URL* as follows:

```bash
$url = "https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6-x64.msi"
$folder = "C:\Users\test\Downloads"

Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile "$folder\$(Split-Path -Leaf $url)"
```